# stop a character jumping in mid-air in javascript

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am creating a platformer in javascript, and I am making a gravity sytem on it. What happens is that gravity is reduced when the player presses the up arrow key. The problem is that the user can press the up arrow multiple times and jump whilst already jumping. Any way to sort this out?
Here is my code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: rgb(0, 200, 200);
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload = "startGame()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="750" height="300">
<script>
var myGamePiece;
var floor;

 function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 230);
  floor = new component(750, 10, "green", 0, 260);
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas : document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
  start : function() {
      this.canvas.width = 480;
      this.canvas.height = 270;
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
      document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
      this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
      window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
          myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
          myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
      })
      window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
          myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
      })
      },
      clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      }
      }

      function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
        this.gamearea = myGameArea;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     this.speedX = 0;
     this.speedY = 0;
     this.gravity = 0.05;
     this.gravitySpeed = 0;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.update = function() {
      ctx = myGameArea.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }

  this.newPos = function() {
      this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
      this.x += this.speedX;
      this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
      this.hitBottom();
    }

  this.hitBottom = function() {
     var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height - 10;
     if (this.y > rockbottom) {
     this.y = rockbottom;
     this.gravitySpeed = 0;
 }
}
}

 function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  floor.update();
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -2.5;
   }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 2.5;   
   }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {
    accelerate(-0.2)
  } else{
    accelerate(0.1)
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 2.5;
   }
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
 }

  function accelerate(n) {
   myGamePiece.gravity = n;
 }
</script>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to check `myGamePiece.y >=230` before accelarting
I have changed only two things in your code and it works fine
`if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40] && myGamePiece.y >= 230)` last if block of your function `updateGameArea()`
**Second Last if block of your `updateGameArea()`**

```
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {
     if(myGamePiece.y >= 230) accelerate(-0.2)
  }
```

```js
var myGamePiece;
var floor;

 function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 230);
  floor = new component(750, 10, "green", 0, 260);
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas : document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
  start : function() {
      this.canvas.width = 480;
      this.canvas.height = 270;
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
      document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
      this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
      window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
          myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
          myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
      })
      window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
          myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
      })
      },
      clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      }
      }

      function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
        this.gamearea = myGameArea;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     this.speedX = 0;
     this.speedY = 0;
     this.gravity = 0.05;
     this.gravitySpeed = 0;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.update = function() {
      ctx = myGameArea.context;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }

  this.newPos = function() {
      this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
      this.x += this.speedX;
      this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
      this.hitBottom();
    }

  this.hitBottom = function() {
     var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height - 10;
     if (this.y > rockbottom) {
     this.y = rockbottom;
     this.gravitySpeed = 0;
 }
}
}

 function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  floor.update();
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -2.5;
   }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 2.5;   
   }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {
     if(myGamePiece.y >= 230) accelerate(-0.2)
  } else{
    accelerate(0.1)
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40] && myGamePiece.y >= 230) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 2.5;
   }
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
 }

  function accelerate(n) {
   myGamePiece.gravity = n;
 }
```

```html
<body onload = "startGame()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="750" height="300">
```

Hope it helps